# How to batch process spatial analyst tools?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I have written the following code to convert my point files of daily max temps to rasters:

```
# Set local variables for Point to Raster Conversion
inFeatures = Day12015Max
valField = "Max_2015"
outRaster = ("Rstr12015Max")
assignmentType = "MOST_FREQUENT"
priorityField = ""
cellSize = 0.05

# Point to Raster conversion for Max values
arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(inFeatures, valField, outRaster, assignmentType, priorityField, cellSize)
```

I have years worth of data so this will be 365x files to process. If all my point files are in a folder, how can I write a script that will go into the folder and go down the list and convert everything and output to a new folder?

I am working with Python 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.3

I have tried the following method:

```
env.workspace = "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles"

#folder to list
shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")

for shpFile in shpFileList:
    # geoprocessing steps
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + "Rast.tif"

arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Max_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)
```

But, this only processes one file and does not seem to loop through.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's show zero research effort.

Comment: @JohnBarça, just edited to include what I have tried so far. Sorry, I am very new and really have no idea where to even start.

Comment: OK, apologies. Being new is fine :-). You just need to show what you have tried and where it went wrong.

Comment: `rastFile = shp + "rast"` --> this becomes `myfile.shprast`

Comment: You need to indent the line calling PointToRaster so it's inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to indent the line calling PointToRaster to include it within the loop.

```
env.workspace = "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles"

#folder to list
shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")

for shpFile in shpFileList:
    # geoprocessing steps
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + "Rast.tif"
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Max_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)
```